# Converting a list-type column to a long form by separating items

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a table with the two columns of interest like this:

> Status_id | hashtag
>   947306525726527488 | NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919
>   947306316959281153 | MakeItALifestyle
>   947306315952611330 | c("Ejuice", "vape", "vaping")
>   947306265520328704 | c("vapefam", "vapenation", "vapefamily")
>   947305941522771968 | nowplaying

```
str(juice) #df name
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ status_id: chr  "947306525726527488" "947306316959281153" 
"947306315952611330" "947306265520328704" 
$ hashtags :List of 5
..$ : chr "NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919"
..$ : chr "MakeItALifestyle"
..$ : chr  "Ejuice" "vape" "vaping" "eliquid"
..$ : chr  "vapefam" "vapenation" "vapefamily"
..$ : chr "nowplaying"
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(status_id = c("947306525726527488", "947306316959281153", 
"947306315952611330", "947306265520328704", "947305941522771968"
), hashtags = list("NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919", "MakeItALifestyle", 
    c("Ejuice", "vape", "vaping", "eliquid", "ecigjuice", "ecig", 
    "vapejuice"), c("vapefam", "vapenation", "vapefamily", "vapelife", 
    "vapelyfe", "vapeon", "positivity"), "nowplaying")), .Names = c("status_id", 
"hashtags"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

**Expected outcome**

I want the following two tables (of course in the actual original df, there are more columns which I removed as they're not relevant to the question):

> df1
>   Status_id
>   947306525726527488
>   947306316959281153
>   947306315952611330
>   947306265520328704
>   947305941522771968

and

> df2
>   status_id  |  hashtag
>   947306525726527488 | NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919
>   947306316959281153 | MakeItALifestyle
>   947306315952611330 | Ejuice
>   947306315952611330 | vape
>   947306315952611330 | vaping
>   947306265520328704 | vapefam
>   947306265520328704 | vapenation
>   947306265520328704 | vapefamily
>   947305941522771968 | nowplaying

The original data has one row per status_id with all the hashtags >1 as c(...) - classed as type: "list". df2 has the individual hashtags separated into separate rows.

Though I've never come across a list type column before and googling it got me loads of stuff on converting a list to a column rather than columns of type "list"

Comment: Maybe something like this `df1 <- df2[, 1, drop = F]`, if your original data set is `df2`.

Comment: original is the very top table above the str() code. df1 and df2 are desired outcomes

Comment: What's the difference between your original data and `df2`?

Comment: the original data has one row per status_id with all the hashtags as c(...) - classed as type: "list". df2 has the individual hashtags separated into separate rows

Comment: Got it. So, for `df1:- df1 <- original[, 1, drop = F]` should work.

Comment: Can you add the data, the way you created it. `dput` it or something.

Comment: note the dput has more hashtags which i removed in the other stuff to keep the question simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. I called your data `mydf`. You have lists in `hashtags`. You can create a vector for each row in `hashtags` using `unlist()` and `paste()`. If you want, you can use `toSting()` instead of `paste()`. Once you have a vector in `hashtags`, you want to split it. Specifically, for the 3rd and 4th row, you have multiple hashtags. You want to split them. You can use `cSplit()` from the `splitstackshape` package. The outcome is what you want as `df2`. Once you have it, you want to create `df1`. You select `status_id` and look for unique `status_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

df2 <- mydf %>%
       rowwise %>%
       mutate(hashtags = paste(unlist(hashtags), collapse = ",")) %>%
       cSplit(splitCols = "hashtags", sep = ",", direction = "long")

             status_id            hashtags
 1: 947306525726527488 NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919
 2: 947306316959281153    MakeItALifestyle
 3: 947306315952611330              Ejuice
 4: 947306315952611330                vape
 5: 947306315952611330              vaping
 6: 947306315952611330             eliquid
 7: 947306315952611330           ecigjuice
 8: 947306315952611330                ecig
 9: 947306315952611330           vapejuice
10: 947306265520328704             vapefam
11: 947306265520328704          vapenation
12: 947306265520328704          vapefamily
13: 947306265520328704            vapelife
14: 947306265520328704            vapelyfe
15: 947306265520328704              vapeon
16: 947306265520328704          positivity
17: 947305941522771968          nowplaying

df1 <- unique(df2[, 1, with = FALSE])

            status_id
1: 947306525726527488
2: 947306316959281153
3: 947306315952611330
4: 947306265520328704
5: 947305941522771968
```

**Revised**

Thanks to the comment by the author of the `splitstackshape` package, we found a better way to handle this task. **`listCol_l()`** is the function that unlists a column stored as a list into a long form. So all the necessary processes can be done in one line.

```
df2 <- listCol_l(mydf, "hashtags")
```

Comment: works perfectly - put this as best answer as it's simplest

Comment: @SaleemKhan Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: @SaleemKhan, since you're already using the "tidyverse", can't you just do `unnest(juice)`?

Comment: Or, using "splitstackshape", `listCol_l(juice, "hashtags")[]` :-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I have not used that function for a long time. A great reminder! Thank you very much. Let me review the function and revise the code above.

Comment: @jazzurro, no problem. Hope all has been going well :-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Indeed, long time no speak. I have been doing good. I cannot come here that often due to work. But I try to come here and learn as much as I can. Your comment allowed me to remember other useful functions in your package. Any potential update for the splitstackshape package?

Comment: It needs to be updated, certainly, but I haven't had much chance to do so. I'm also not here very much now--just came back for the winter hats :-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I see. Hats are attractive, aren't they? :) If I can be of any help, I am happy to give you a hand for the update.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

rm(list=ls())

k <- c(LETTERS[1:5])
v <- list('a','b', c('c','d','e'), c('f','g'), 'h')
df <- cbind(k, v) %>% as.data.frame(df)
df

df.temp <- df %>% mutate(vn = sapply(v, length)) 
k <- rep(df.temp$k, df.temp$vn, each=TRUE) %>% unlist
v <- unlist(df.temp$v)

df2 <- data.frame(k, v)
df1 <- df$k %>% unlist %>% data.frame(k=.)

df1
df2
```

- result

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good thinking to arrive a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(juice)[, .(hashtag = unlist(hashtags)), by = status_id]
df1 <- unique(juice[, .(status_id)])

df2
```

> ```
>              status_id             hashtag
>  1: 947306525726527488 NEWYEARSEVEPARTY919
>  2: 947306316959281153    MakeItALifestyle
>  3: 947306315952611330              Ejuice
>  4: 947306315952611330                vape
>  5: 947306315952611330              vaping
>  6: 947306315952611330             eliquid
>  7: 947306315952611330           ecigjuice
>  8: 947306315952611330                ecig
>  9: 947306315952611330           vapejuice
> 10: 947306265520328704             vapefam
> 11: 947306265520328704          vapenation
> 12: 947306265520328704          vapefamily
> 13: 947306265520328704            vapelife
> 14: 947306265520328704            vapelyfe
> 15: 947306265520328704              vapeon
> 16: 947306265520328704          positivity
> 17: 947305941522771968          nowplaying
> ```

```
df1
```

> ```
>             status_id
> 1: 947306525726527488
> 2: 947306316959281153
> 3: 947306315952611330
> 4: 947306265520328704
> 5: 947305941522771968
> ```